# Advanced Custom Fields Wysiwyg Editor - No font color

Tags: wordpress

For some reason, I don’t have any option to change the font color in ACF wysiwyg editor (latest ACF and WP version, TinyMCE 4.1.7 also installed). Any idea why?

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to click the icon to expand the toolbar -- it's the icon on the far right as shown here:

[image: Collapsed WP WYSIWYG Toolbar]

Once you do that, you will see the option for changing the font color as illustrated here:

[image: Expanded WP WYSIWYG Toolbar with Text color highlighted]

These screenshots were taken from the latest versions of ACF and WP, so they should look just like yours.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I did not think it is more tools icon. :D

Answer (score 0):

I did that. It turns out the that problem is a bug, when the CMS is in HEBREW, there is no expand toolbar button.